# IE8 transition on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I want to use transition effect on hover for IE 8 like in this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/evcL2/10/
According to **[this site](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/DXTidemo/DXTidemo.htm)** (is working only on ie) that is possible (use trasntion option and fade effect) but I am not able to use it. Can someone help me a little bit with that script, for me is simportant to have that transition on hover only for background color.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

IE8 doesn't support CSS3 transitions. You'll have to fake it using JavaScript tweens, or settle for IE9 support. IE8 users don't deserve nice looking websites anyway :-)

But if you're in the awkward position of being tasked with creating IE compatible stuff, take a look at this [MSDN introduction to Filters and Transitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx#Transitions). It appears that even the IE specific transition filters require JavaScript to work, so you might as well go with the proper JavaScript solution of using [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). With a small plugin it can animate colors. [Here's an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gu9XQ/).

Comment: Yes, if you have checked that site from description you'll see there is a js script but must be modified to use background color and not image and i'm not able to do that :|

Comment: +1 for `IE8 users don't deserve nice looking websites anyway`. I would say it should be IE 9 or below users

Comment: yes I know ... but I must have the same look on ie8,chrome,ff and safari

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the website you suggested doesn't render properly in my browser. However, I think you may be attacking the problem wrongly. I would use [jQuery's $.animate() function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for this, as it is very cross browser and can animate gradual changes in many css properties.

Comment: yes is rendering well only on ie browsers. i'm not sure this .animate() can help me much on IE8...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will work; try http://api.jquery.com/animate/#entry-examples in ie8.